# CocoaAsyncSocket not giving socket disconnected when other party disconnects abruptly

Tags: ios, cocoaasyncsocket

Has anybody worked in cocoaAsyncSocket for a TCP connection??? I am not getting socket disconnected when TCP connection is abruptly disconnected by other party?? or can anyone suggest a good TCP connection library which is reliable?

Comment: I assumed that you were referring to socketDidDisconnect?  What about the didAcceptNewSocket?

Comment: How is that related I didn't override didAcceptNewSocket method!!

Comment: Hi, did you solve this problem?